# How can I bypass websites that block direct connections?

Tags: c, sockets, http, http-headers, ip-address

I'm trying to access the website `https://www.000webhost.com` with C sockets:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
    struct hostent *hp;
    int sock_id;
    char message[1024*1024];
    char request[] = "GET / HTTP/1.1\n" "From: ...\n";

    //get a socket  
    if((sock_id = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Couldn't get a socket.\n"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }else {
        fprintf(stderr,"Got a socket.\n");
    }

    memset(&servaddr,0,sizeof(servaddr));

    //get address
    if((hp = gethostbyname("000webhost.com")) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Couldn't get an address.\n"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }else {
        fprintf(stderr,"Got an address.\n");
    }

    memcpy((char *)&servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr, (char *)hp->h_addr, hp->h_length);

    //port number and type
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(80);
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;

    //connect
    if(connect(sock_id, (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't connect.\n");
    }else {
        fprintf(stderr,"Got a connection.\n");
    }

    //request
    write(sock_id,request,strlen(request));

    //response
    read(sock_id,message,1024*1024);

    fprintf(stdout,"%s",message);

    return 0;
}
```

If I change the `request[]` array from `"GET / HTTP/1.1\n" "From: ...\n"` to `"GET / HTTP/1.1\n" "Host: https://www.000webhost.com" "From: ...\n"` (therefore removing the direct-IP adress from the request), I still get the error `Error 1003. Direct IP access not allowed`. Is there some other part of the request that I need to modify? What else do I need to do?

Comment: Your request is malformed, the line separator must be `\r\n`. After each single line. Also HTTP1.1 absolutely doesn't work without Host header, so please stop trying that and produce a [mcve] that is according to your best knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Your request is malformed:

- Each line needs to be terminated by `\r\n`, not just `\n`. (Some web servers will let you get away with `\n`, but I have no idea whether that'll work on 000webhost.)
- Every header needs a `\r\n` after it. The modified code you mention in the last paragraph is missing a `\r\n` at the end of the `Host` header.
- The `Host` header needs to just be a hostname (e.g, `"Host: example.com"`). Don't include `http://`.